# Wait for POST request gets completed before loading scripts in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

Here is my code snippet, In my case scripts gets loaded first before getting POST response. How to wait for POST request gets completed before loading scripts?

```
myfunction = function() {

$http.post(Url, requestData).success(
            function(response) {
              for (i = 0; i < response.result[0].length; i++) {                if (response.result[0][i].isActive) {
                  status.push({
                    name: response.result[0][i].Name
                  })
                }
              }
              deferred.resolve(permissions);
              },
            function(error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
            }
          );
          return deferred.promise;   
           }
   }
```

Calling from my controller

```
   var status = myfunction();
    status.then(function(result) {
         console.log("data.name"+ result);
       });
      // Then do the scripts after POST reququest gets completed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do it after your post method is finished you must do it in the 'then' part of the promise :

```
var status = myfunction();
status.then(function(result) {
     console.log("data.name"+ result);
     // -----> HERE <-----
     // Then do the scripts after POST reququest gets completed.

   });
```